# Printing thumbnail images in DomPDF

Tags: files

My print-friendly version replaces the thumbnail images with the hi-res versions which is fine, but the PDF version replaces the images with the alt tag.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can get the PDF varsion (DomPDF) to behave when dealing with the thumbnails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a setting in the admin/content/node-type/[your node type]/display (Display Fields settings). The "Print" tab was set to show the images, but PDF uses the "Basic" settings. Changing the "Teaser" setting to "thumbnail" fixed the problem.